# Install a later version of skopeo on 22.04

Tags: package-management

I need a version of skopeo later than 1.6 when it run apt-get update and install i get 1.4.1 how can I get a later version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: No that does not answer my question, I am asking if there is a way I can install the newer version even if it is not included in the apt library

Comment: Sure: Download it from upstream and read the INSTALL file to figure out how to install it (since it won't be packaged). Note that this defeats the entire purpose of using an LTS --stability through unchanged software-- as you will be changing the software.

Comment: To avoid hard-coded (i.e. strictly correct but not future-proof) answers specifying the targeted Ubuntu version should be probably accompanied by changing "a later" to "the latest" which is probably what was meant?

Answer (score 0):

You could install Ubuntu 23.04.

The 23.04 repositories include Skopeo 1.9.

Comment: I feel, this could have been a comment.

Comment: @Levente this directly answers the question that was asked: "*How can I get a later version?*" Other answers are welcome, even short answers if little explanation is required.